# Syntax changes from the examples in 'The Little Schemer' to the real Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, the-little-schemer

I have recently started following the examples from [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) and when trying out the examples in [DrScheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/), I have realised that there are some minor syntax changes from the examples in the book to what I can write in DrScheme.

First of all, as a language in DrScheme, I chose `Pretty Big` (one of the Legacy Languages).
Is this the correct choice for trying the examples in the book?

---

As regards the syntax changes I have noticed that, for example, I need to prefix the identifiers with a `'` in order for them to work.

For example:

```
(rember 'jelly '(peanut butter jelly))
```

Are there any more changes (syntactical or not) that I need to be aware of when trying the examples from the 'The Little Schemer' book ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, the book uses a different font for quoted pieces of data, and in real Scheme code that requires using quote.  As for your use of PLT Scheme -- the "Pretty Big" language is really there just as a legacy language.  You should use the `Module` language, and have all files start with `#lang scheme` (which should be there by default).

(The "new" way of using different languages in DrScheme is to always be in the `Module` "language" and specify the actual language using a `#lang` line.)

Comment: +1 Thanks for suggesting the `Module` language and `#lang scheme`

Answer (score 2):

See the "Guidelines for the reader" section in the Preface. (I'm looking at the 4th edition here.)

Comment: yes but still, for example, the `'` thing is not mentioned there

Comment: That is mentioned on page 3, the first time it's needed. You do need to read everything in order; I'd forgotten to note that, as it's been years.